# Archives downloaded with CURL not valid

Tags: php, curl, zip, archive, fputs

I have a PHP script that downloads automatically some zip files from certain URLs with cURL functions.

But there's a problem: zip archives downloaded with CURL, if opened with Windows native Zip Extractor, it gives me an "invalid archive" error. If I download the zip file from URL with my browser, it is ok.

For example: zip downloaded with CURL is 21,8 Kb and the one downloaded from browser is 21,4 Kb.

Here's my Curl Setup:

```
curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_URL, $link);
curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE);
$data  = curl_exec($this->ch);
```

Then I save the file ($data) locally on my website like this:

```
$file = fopen($full_path, "w+");
fputs($file, $data);
fclose($file);
```

With WinRar both zips are fine, but I need the script to download zip files that are 100% valid.

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the solution: CURLOPT_HEADER must be set to false, otherwise it will write HTTP headers in response (and so in my zip files).